# The parameter ‘path’ is required. in my functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys so I have been working on my functions.php page for a custom Wordpress theme of mine and can't figure out the issue... It is something between lines 0 - 10...   Some things I have read relate it to the get_stylesheet_uri()   Please help... I am only new to Wordpress and can't figure this out...

```
    <?php

    function asns_resources()  {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'asns_resources');



    //Custom Appearance
    function allsugar_customise_register(  $wp_customize ){

    $wp_customize->add_setting('asns_link_colour', array(
    'default' => '#f4f4f8',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));


$wp_customize->add_section('asns_standard_colours', array(
    'title' => __('Standard Colours', 'AllSugar-NoSpice'),
    'priority' => 30,
));


$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'asns_link_colour_control', array(
    'label' => __('Link Colour', 'AllSugar-NoSpice'),
    'section' => 'asns_standard_colours',
    'settings' => 'asns_link_colour',

) ) );
}

add_action('customize_register', 'allsugar_customise_register');



?>
```

Comment: php must give you the exact line where the error occured. Can you show this line and what function was called?

Comment: Nah this only shows up in the editor - I'm using godaddy's one on the server...   As u can see on my website (http://clothingstoretheme.nextleveldesign.co.nz) it shows just a blank screen however with the background colour of mine (#f4f4f8) which I added in the index.php as a bgcolour to the body...

Comment: Ill upload a screenshot

Comment: http://clothingstoretheme.nextleveldesign.co.nz/wp-content/themes/screenshot1.png

Comment: Actually I just removed the code which I thought was the issue and it still shows up so it is do with the first few lines

Comment: Keep removing the function calls line by line to find what's causing the issue.

Comment: Call to undefined function action() in /home/jaydenszekely/public_html/clothingstoretheme/wp-content/themes/AllSugar-NoSpice/functions.php on line 36   I just got this...

Comment: Great. Where is this function?

Comment: Thats what I was confused about... It is the line before the closing php tag...

Comment: Ok so I played With it and now it is working...\

Comment: Thanks for the help ;p  It was one of those where u just had to muck around until I found it haha

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that before. Only it was when editing via the cPanel File Manager.

**I found the cause of the problem was that I had changed the name of the file/folder after I had already opened the file to edit it.**

All I had to do was copy the contents of the file to the clipboard then close the tab in the browser and just re-access that same file again and then paste the code with all the changes I had made before and VOILA!! It successfully saved and "The parameter ‘path’ is required" error was gone.